# Display YUV(yuv420p) is not correct on IOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsl, textures, opengl-es-2.0

Using (`EAGLRenderingAPI api = kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2`) to displaying YUV on the screen on iOS.
But I got this problem, and how to deal with this problem thanks.

Display YUV (size-> 3268:1838) isn't correct, showing as:

[image]

But using the same code TO Display YUV(size-> 1280:720) is correct, showing as:

[image]

WHAT IS WRONG? ANY HELP thanks.

CODES:

```
EAGLRenderingAPI api = kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2;
_context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:api];
if (!_context)
{
    if([LTJNYJCommon isDebug]){NSLog(@"Failed to initialize OpenGLES 2.0 context");}
    exit(1);
}

if (![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:_context])
{
    if([LTJNYJCommon isDebug]){NSLog(@"Failed to set current OpenGLES 2.0 context");}
    exit(1);
}


    int idxU = width * height;
    int idxV = idxU + (idxU / 4);
    uint8_t *pyuvData = (uint8_t *)[data bytes];

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glViewport(x, y, w, h);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(_positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(LTGLVertex), 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(_texCoordSlot, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(LTGLVertex), (GLvoid *)(offsetof(LTGLVertex, TexCoord)));


        //----------------------------------------------------
        //Y texture
        //----------------------------------------------------
        if (_samplerYTexture){glDeleteTextures(1, &_samplerYTexture);}
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glGenTextures(1, &_samplerYTexture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _samplerYTexture);
        glUniform1i(_samplerYUniform, 0);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, width, height, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pyuvData);
        //----------------------------------------------------
        //U texture
        //----------------------------------------------------
        if (_samplerUTexture){glDeleteTextures(1, &_samplerUTexture);}
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glGenTextures(1, &_samplerUTexture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _samplerUTexture);
        glUniform1i(_samplerUUniform, 1);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        if (datalength>idxU && pyuvData[idxU]) {
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, width/2, height/2, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &pyuvData[idxU]);
        }else{
            if([LTJNYJCommon isDebug]){NSLog(@"error1");}
        }
        //----------------------------------------------------
        //V texture
        //----------------------------------------------------
        if (_samplerVTexture){glDeleteTextures(1, &_samplerVTexture);}
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
        glGenTextures(1, &_samplerVTexture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _samplerVTexture);
        glUniform1i(_samplerVUniform, 2);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        if (datalength>idxV && pyuvData[idxV]) {
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, width/2, height/2, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &pyuvData[idxV]);
        }else{
            if([LTJNYJCommon isDebug]){NSLog(@"error2");}
        }
        //----------------------------------------------------
        //glDrawElements
        //----------------------------------------------------
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, sizeof(LTGLIndices)/sizeof(GLubyte), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

//SHADER

```
precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D samplerY;
uniform sampler2D samplerU;
uniform sampler2D samplerV;

varying highp vec2 TexCoordOut;

const highp mat3 yuv2rgb = mat3(1, 1, 1,
                                0, -0.39465, 2.03211,
                                1.13983, -0.58060, 0);
void main(void)
{
    highp vec3 yuv;
    yuv.x = texture2D(samplerY, TexCoordOut).r;
    yuv.y = texture2D(samplerU, TexCoordOut).r - 0.5;
    yuv.z = texture2D(samplerV, TexCoordOut).r - 0.5;

    vec3 rgb = yuv2rgb * yuv;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(rgb, 1.0);
}

//
attribute vec4 Position;
attribute vec2 TexCoordIn;

uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 Modelview;

varying vec2 TexCoordOut;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = Position;
    TexCoordOut = TexCoordIn;
}
```

Comment: Try `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);`, before the texture images are specified (before `glTexImage2D`).

Comment: @Rabbid76 nice try, it working for me. please put it on the ANSWER.THEN set fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default OpenGL assumes that the start of each row of an image is aligned 4 bytes. This is because the [`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) parameter by default is 4.
Since the images have 1 (`GL_LUMINANCE`) channel with a sizof 1 byte, and are tightly packed the start of a row is possibly misaligned.
Change the the [`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) parameter to 1, before specifying the two-dimensional texture image (`glTexImage2D`).

Note `glPixelStorei` changes a global state, so it is sufficient to set the parameter once, before the texture images are specified by `glTexImage2D`.

```cpp
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```

If you don't set the alignment correctly, then this causes a shift effect at row of the texture and finally the image buffer is accessed out of bounds.

Note, the issue is cause by the `width` of the first texture which is 3268. So 
`widht/2` is 1634. 1634 is not divisible by 4 (1634/4 = 408,5).
In compare the `width` of the 2nd texture is 1280. `widht/2` is 640 and that is  divisible by 4.
Actually  an alignment of 2 (`glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 2);`) would solve the issue, too (in this special case).

Comment: In 4-byte alignment mode, OpenGL will read 32 bytes of data, which will cause the read of the function in glTextImage to be out of bounds, thus completely crashing, this status will be happening?

Comment: @JNYJ Is this a question? A crash may occur (since the memory is read, it depends on if the memory is accessible) and indeed the array is read out of bounds.